# Convert a pandas dataframe to a PySpark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a script with the below setup.

I am using:

1) Spark dataframes to pull data in
2) Converting to pandas dataframes after initial aggregatioin
3) Want to convert back to Spark for writing to HDFS

The conversion from Spark --> Pandas was simple, but I am struggling with how to convert a Pandas dataframe back to spark.

Can you advise?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
import pandas as pd

def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('yarn')\
        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://uds-far-mn1.dab.02.net:9083")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session
### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('testing_files')
```

I've tried the below - no errors, just no data! To confirm, df6 does have data & is a pandas dataframe

```
df6 = df5.sort_values(['sdsf'], ascending=["true"])
sdf = spark_session.createDataFrame(df6)
sdf.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Pault - unfortunately, that solution doesn't work - I've added the attempted & failed code at the bottom. I'm not entirely sure what the issue is

Comment: Can u share ur answer?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here we go:

```
# Spark to Pandas
df_pd = df.toPandas()

# Pandas to Spark
df_sp = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_pd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the post to show trying this - it doesn't error, but it doesn't provide any output

Comment: For those who wants to read more, [this Medium article](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/5-steps-to-converting-python-jobs-to-pyspark-4b9988ad027a) is useful.